# Play next youtube video from a list when the actual ends

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, youtube-api

I'm reading the "iframe_api_reference" and I want to make something like a playlist that plays the next video after the actual video ends, so...

Based on this:

```
<div id = "player" style = "height: 390; width: 590;"></div>
<script src="http://www.youtube.com/player_api"></script> 
<script>
    var player;
    function onYouTubePlayerAPIReady() {
        player = new YT.Player('player', {
          height: '390',
          width: '590',
          videoId: "4kpXVR6LavI",
          events: {
            'onReady': onPlayerReady,
            'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
          }
        });
    }
    function onPlayerReady(event) {
        event.target.playVideo();
    }
    function onPlayerStateChange(event) {        
        if(event.data === 0) { 
            alert("over");         
        }
    }
</script>
```

I want to take the next video from something like this:

```
<div class="youtube" id="4kpXVR6LavI">
    <p>Video title</p>
    <img src="portraitphoto" alt="">
</div>
```

How I can make this? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add event listener to your app. [`player.addEventListener(event:String, listener:String):Void`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/js_api_reference#Adding_event_listener). The listener is a string that specifies the function that will execute when the specified event fires.

Include [`onStateChange`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/js_api_reference#Events), this event fires whenever the player's state changes. The value that the API passes to your event listener function will specify an integer that corresponds to the new player state.

```
function onYouTubePlayerReady(playerId) {
    ytplayer = document.getElementById("myytplayer");
    ytplayer.addEventListener("onStateChange", "onytplayerStateChange");
}

function onytplayerStateChange(newState) {
    alert("Player's new state: " + newState);
}
```

Bind your custom function as the handler to the `"onStateChange"` event, and evaluate the new state from within. According to the Events portion of the API, you're looking for state `0`, indicating the video has ended.

```
function onytplayerStateChange(newState) {
    if ( newState == 0 ) {
        /* load next video */
    }
}
```